# Explode expect if there is "

Tags: php

I'm trying to explode a string with commas, but in the string are some commas I don't want to get explode, those commas are between `" "` like: `"hey, how are you"`. I tried multiple things like exploding the `"` first. So how can I do this?

For example i have this string:

```
hey,how,are,"yo how,are you?",i'm,good
```

So the output will be:

```
array (
    0 => hey,
    1 => how,
    2 => are,
    3 => "you how, are you?",
    4 => i'm,
    5 => good
);
```

I tried to explode first on `"` that but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) for PHP >= 5.3:

```
var_dump( str_getcsv( 'hey,how,are,"yo how,are you?"'));
```

This prints:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "hey" [1]=> string(3) "how" [2]=> string(3) "are" [3]=> string(15) "yo how,are you?" }
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, but what if i want to explode a other thing then comma's ?? Now i do use a CSV So it works! thanks, and the function looks great on php.net 

So is there any other function what does the same?? But more like explode, or doesn;t that exsists?

Comment: Check the documentation, one of the parameters to `str_getcsv` is the delimiter to use (the second one).

Comment: Ahh, indeed :) Thank you! You're a great help!

Comment: The third parameter could be also interesting in future. There you can say which character defines a text. Default is ".